# Nginx error "502 BAD GATEWAY" on GCP's VM instance

Tags: nginx, web, google-cloud-platform, devops

I am trying to deploy my website on VM instance via Nginx. Nginx does not allow to access website even i configured app.conf

Error on Nginx:

> 2023/07/22 12:33:46 [error] 22397#22397: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 78.27.118.50, server: 35.228.211.143, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "35.228.211.143"

[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJpls.png)
[app.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHlzs.png)

I dont have any idea to fix it. Everything seems correctly